# Redirect only non existing file

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
```

I have this code, and i cannot find the mistake. 
It should redirect only non-folders and urls where there is no file,but it redirects everything.
Is there anything wrong with this code ? Or does any apache config rule exist, which could cause this behaviour ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
## If file or directory exists behave normally
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]

## But for everything else that doesn't exist, run it through my index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index\.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```